# How to access returned variables from a function

Tags: php

This is the script that uses the "login" function and it returns two variables, how come in here when I try to take them from the sanitize function to the "login" function it doesn't work

index.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
{
include("check.php");
$class = new check;
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$results = $class->sanitize($user, $pass);
$class->login($results[0], $results[1]);
//$class->login($user, $pass);
}
?>
```

check.php

```
function sanitize($string, $string2)
{
    $stringh = htmlentities($string);
    $string1h = htmlentities($string2);
    $stringht = trim($stringh);
    $string1ht = trim($string1h);
    return $stringht;
    return $string1ht;
}

function login($user, $pass)
{
    $result = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `username` = '".$user."'");
    $numbers = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($numbers != 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $dbuser = $row['username'];
            $dbpass = $row['password'];
        }

        if($dbuser == $user && $dbpass == $pass)
        {
            echo "You have a match.";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can only return 1 variable from a function. If you need two, wrap them in an array, giving you one object being returned.

```
return array($stringht, $string1ht);
```

However, a better solution may be to make your sanitize accept one input and have one output, and just call it twice, once for each string.

Comment: Or, accept an array on input and return an array on output.

Comment: Thank you. @collin never knew that.

Comment: They are already doing that, lascort.

Comment: What would i have to do if i wanted my variables still pass through the "sanitize" function but only calling the "login" function from the index so basically the "login" function uses the "sanitize" function in it already? @CollinGrady